# Connection close not returning

Tags: java, connection, jms

I have a JMS client which is consuming messages from a queue using the following code:

```
    try {

        ...

        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(getNextFile(), txtMessage.getText());                   

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());          
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());          
    }finally{
        if(this.openMessages<=0){
            try {
                if(transacted){
                    session.commit();
                    LOG.info("Session commited");
                }

                consumer.close();           

//              System.exit(0);             
                closeSession();                 

                System.exit(0);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOG.error("Error while closing the consumer and session.", e);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                LOG.error("Global Exception while closing the consumer and session.", e2);
            }           
        }           
    }

public void closeSession() throws JMSException {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.stop();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

After closing the consumer I want to close the session. For closing it made a method call `closeSession` which stops the connection and closes it. Unfortunately, due to some reason, sometimes, calling `close` is NOT returning. Therefore I've added an `exit` statement (now commented) in the code snippet above. Following the Interface documentation we have:

> When this method is invoked, it should not return until message processing has been shut down in an orderly fashion. This means that all message listeners that may have been running have returned, and that all pending receives have returned.

Which is NOT my case, because I know that all messages have been processed.

Any hint why this is *sometimes* not working?

Comment: Can you make a thread dump when `close()` is blocking? `jstack`/`jconsole` or JVisualVM will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for a `System.exit(0)` call in your code.

I see lots of code for stopping stuff, but I don't see any processing.

You're overthinking this.  Your `MessageListener` looks far too complex compared to the way I've done it in the past.  I'd simplify.  The listener doesn't have to disappear and nuke the JVM on which it's running.  All it has to do is finish, close its connection, and let the app server put it back into the pool to wait for the next message arriving on the queue.